# How to set norm for multiple plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Doing `plt.set_cmap('coolwarm')` one can set the `coolwarm` colormap as default. I also want to set a normalization like [`CenteredNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#centered) for multiple plots.

The motivation for my question is to avoid having a keyword parameter `norm=CenteredNorm(vcenter=0)` in all my `pcolor` calls.

Despite search attempts in the [docs for normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) and [for colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and about the [cm namespace](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html) (I'm not sure if that's just a namespace or a class), I haven't found a way to do that. Maybe it is because I don't understand deeply how they work. Can someone help?

Comment: If I understand your issue, you can't do what you want.  Each plot needs a separate instance of `CenteredNorm`, allowing for each different range of the data to be reflected in the normalization.

Comment: I don't think this functionality is supported.  Also, in case it would work, it could lead to hard-to-track strange behaviors, especially if such a setting would be called somewhere inside an innocent function. I would strongly recommend to explicitly write `norm=CenteredNorm(vcenter=0)` whenever you want to use that norm. For libraries such as matplotlib, predictability is highly desired.

Comment: `def centered_pcolor(C, **kwds): return plt.pcolor(C,norm=CenteredNorm(vcenter=0) , **kwds)`

Comment: @gboffi, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.